# Is it possible to attack or kill NPCs from faraway places using a bow?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was wondering if this was really possible. Lets say I'm at the Markarth Stables, and I use a bow for this. My target is at the Riften Stables, that guy who you can brawl with. If I use a bow an arrow, from a faraway place, an I'm able to attempt to shoot it faraway, will it kill NPCs from that faraway place? Can I kill anyone with a bow and arrow who's faraway?

Comment: I'm curious as to the reason for the downvote here. Seems a perfectly fair question to me.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't. Bows have only a limited range. And even when they would not, you can't interact with any object which is not in the currently loaded grid cells (invisible sections of the world) around your player-character because the game doesn't calculate any game mechanics for them.

Comment: So, is it because of game memory/

Comment: @Jim, yeah pretty much. If an entity is in an unloaded area, they just don't exist. The game does this so it doesn't have the entire game loaded all at once. If it did, it simply would not be able to run at all.

Comment: There is a mod wich makes a nice Cam Tracing of your Arrows so if you shoot your camara gets detached and followes the arrow wich could help you to understand how far the arrow works http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/?

Comment: For some more clarity: There are 2 things at work.  Bows have a naturally limited range (60-65 yards, according to http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Archery_(Skyrim) ) - probably done for optimization purposes, plus it's unreasonable for an arrow to hit an object that hasn't been loaded (as philipp states).